# MVC5 app handling generic errors with mysterious behavior

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a generic authentication error which does not seem to hit any debug points, and ALWAYS sends the user to "/home/error".

I've searched far and wide, web.config, routing, etc... and can find no trace of a default error handling sending users to /home/error

I would really like to handle my own exceptions with custom messages, and this is preventing that. Any idea where I can look to find some manner of default error handling?

Comment: which kind of authentication do you use ? did you search a filter ? onexception method in base controller ?

Comment: have your checked `global.asax` with it's `Application_Error`?

Comment: Looks like it might be in the `RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)` section. When I comment out `HandleErrorAttribute()` I get a good old fashion unhandled error